# what is the difference of built-in function and myfunction

Tags: python

If I use this

```
def myfunction():
    print('asd')
print(myfunction)
```

The IDE tells me `None`

but if I use this

```
import math
print (math.cos(90))
```

The IDE tells me the `COS90°`

Why?

Comment: @Kidus the only problem with that is that the OP never calls the function, so the return value is irrelevant. The code posted will print out the function object instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When functions are called they always **return** something they processes.

```
def myfunction():
    print('asd')
```

This will **print** the output. Since there is nothing explicitly returned, the function by default return `None`

Now lets add a bit of complexity to your function:

```
def myfunction(text):
    print(text * 2)
```

This will print the text it gets twice. And it works just fine. But lets say you need to store the "printed twice" text to a variable.

---

Try this:

```
def myfunction(text):
    print(text * 2)

twoText = myFunction("some text foo")
print(twoText)
```

Output should look like this:

```
some text foosome text foo
None
```

This is happening because you are in your function first **printing** twice `some text foo` and then **printing** what your function **returned**. In this case it **returned** `None` since nothing was explicitly **returned**.

---

To fix this you just replace `print` with `return`.

```
def myfunction(text):
    return text * 2

twoText = myFunction("some text foo")
print(twoText)
```

The output is correct because you print only the return of the function.

```
some text foosome text foo
```

---

The math function returnes data like this:

```
def cos(number):
    # Insert super complex math calculation here
    return result
```

If it didn't do this you would not be able to store the result in a variable, instead it would just be printed.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about return value.

```
def myfun(x):
    return x
```

`print(myfun("hello"))`  will return `hello`.

Your function (`myfunction`) does not return a value, that's to say it returns None value. So, print (a built in python function) returns that value.

Comment: Your use of "return" is confusing. `print` _always_ returns `None`. If you do `print(myfun("hello"))`, the `print` calls _return_ `None` and `hello` will be printed to the terminal. But it's inaccurate to say that `print(myfun("hello"))` returns `hello`

Answer (score 0):

If a Question is general than there is no difference except built-in function is one that is properly tested and approved by author's command; You can contribute too if You write something good and useful - don't shy offer it to community; ppl will thank You.
But if You mean exactly Your example then You have to change code to be:

```
def myfunction():
    print('asd')
myfunction()
```

this is the way to call function without arguments, You could have

```
def myfunction(n):
    print(n)
myfunction('hi')
```

this would print hi and so on